# Can't find git executable

Tags: macos, emacs, magit

I'm using Emacs 24 on OS X 10.6.8. Doing `magit-status` says

> Searching for program: no such file or directory, git

However, the Emacs shell is able to find `git`, so this does not seem to be a `$PATH` issue. What else could it be?

Comment: The emacs shell reads the shell startup file which needn't apply to Emacs, so it could still be a `$PATH` issue. Evaluate `(insert (getenv "PATH"))` in a buffer to see the value of `PATH` Emacs uses to start external commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking the value of `exec-path` variable.  This controls the directories which are looked by Emacs for external executables (including git).

This is a customizable variable, and you can add the path to `git` to the list of existing directories.

I have the elisp snippet in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file for my Emacs install under OSX, which sets both the `PATH` and `exec-path` correctly.

```lisp
;;; Set localized PATH for OS X
(defun my-add-path (path-element)
  "Add the specified PATH-ELEMENT to the Emacs PATH."
  (interactive "DEnter directory to be added to path: ")
  (if (file-directory-p path-element)
     (progn
       (setenv "PATH" (concat (expand-file-name path-element) path-separator (getenv "PATH")))
       (add-to-list 'exec-path (expand-file-name path-element)))))

(if (fboundp 'my-add-path)
   (let ((my-paths (list "/opt/local/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/git/bin")))
      (dolist (path-to-add my-paths (getenv "PATH"))
         (my-add-path path-to-add))))
```

Comment: You need to parse the files under `/etc/path.d/`, too, or executables from 3rd party installers will not be available.  Prominent example is MacTeX which puts executables into `/usr/texbin/`.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs on OS X uses the system-wide environment variables, which can be overridden by creating a magic `environment.plist` XML file in the right directory. A better solution, though, is to have Emacs copy the value of `$PATH` from your shell, so that it matches what you see in `Terminal.app`.

@Anupam's answer is based on a snippet of code which I originally wrote for this purpose, but I've now improved that code and published it as a [little elisp library called `exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) which you can install from Marmalade or [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net).

Comment: +1 for the idea of getting `$PATH` from the shell and putting this idea into a package.